# https login using curl

Tags: php, curl, https

I'm trying to login on https://www.investagrams.com/login using curl and It just show blank page. I'm new to curl btw so please bear with me. Can someone kindly point out what's the problem in my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

// Create temp file to store cookies
$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");

// URL to login page
$url = "https://www.investagrams.com/login";

// Get Login page and its cookies and save cookies in the temp file
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Accepts all CAs
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

$fields = array(
'ctl00$WelcomePageMainContent$ctl00$Username' => '******',
'ctl00$WelcomePageMainContent$ctl00$Password' => '******',
);

$fields_string = '';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
$fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
}
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

// Post login form and follow redirects
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Accepts all CAs
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);


$url = "https://www.investagrams.com/Stock/RealTimeMonitoring";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Accepts all CAs
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch); 

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're first url appears to be missing the `.com`

Comment: You need to return the value of $output after it's second declaration.

Comment: I tried removing the first $output and echo the second $output but still returns blank page @C.Liddell

Comment: thanks bro, but still returns blank page @Terminus

Comment: You also don't need to add a DOCTYPE declaration, html, or body tags in your code since that will be returned with the curl request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things I noticed wrong with your code:

1. You need to return the value of your second curl request.
2. You do not need to declare DOCTYPE or use an `<html>` or `<body>` tag if your using curl to pull down information from a website that will already be wrapped in those tags.
3. As @Terminus mentioned in a comment on your question, you need to include a `.com` at the end of the first URL.

After these revisions your code should be:

```
<?php

// Create temp file to store cookies
$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");

// URL to login page
$url = "https://www.investagrams.com/login";

// Get Login page and its cookies and save cookies in the temp file
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); // Accepts all CAs
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

$fields = array(
'ctl00$WelcomePageMainContent$ctl00$Username' => '******',
'ctl00$WelcomePageMainContent$ctl00$Password' => '******',
);

$fields_string = '';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
$fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
}
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

// Post login form and follow redirects
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); // Accepts all CAs
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);

$url = "https://www.investagrams.com/Stock/RealTimeMonitoring";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); // Accepts all CAs
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;

?>
```

Edit:

As @Tom Stated in a comment below, you should not use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` unless absolutely necessary, what happens is it doesn't verify the SSL certificate provided by the server allowing for impersonation of any server curl connects to.

Additionally, since https://investagrams.com has a valid SSL certificate there is no reason for you to have `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` set to false.

Comment: WOW! it works bro thank you. You save me a lot of time

Comment: @C.Liddell You should add a warning about CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER because it's has serious security implications.

Comment: @Tom Good catch. Added notice to question.